# Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in 'id_cliente'

Tags: django, ajax

I am trying to add the sale of products to the database but it turns out that when I try to do it I get the following error:

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in 'id_cliente'
```

I had to add some lines to the ajax code because otherwise another error would appear

I hope you can help me

JS

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        ventas.items.id_cliente = $('input[name="id_cliente"]').val();
        ventas.items.fecha_venta = $('input[name="fecha_venta"]').val();
        ventas.items.forma_pago = $('input[name="forma_pago"]').val();
        ventas.items.precio_total = $('input[name="precio_total"]').val();

        var parametros = new FormData();
        parametros.append('action', $('input[name="action"]').val());
        parametros.append('ventas', JSON.stringify(ventas.items));
        submit(window.location.pathname, parametros, function () {
            location.href = 'crear_venta';
        });
```

Views

```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = {}
        try:
            action = request.POST['action']
            if action == 'autocomplete':
                productos = Producto.objects.filter(
                    nombre__icontains=request.POST['term'])[0:10]
                for i in productos:
                    data = []
                    item = i.toJSON()
                    item['value'] = i.nombre
                    data.append(item)

            elif action == 'add':
                #vents = request.POST['ventas']
                ventas = json.loads(request.POST['ventas'])
                print(ventas)
                venta = Venta()
                venta.id_cliente = int(ventas['id_cliente'])
                venta.id_empleado = int(ventas['id_empleado'])
                venta.fecha_venta = ventas['fecha_venta']
                venta.forma_pago = ventas['forma_pago']
                venta.precio_total = float(ventas['precio_total'])
                venta.save()

                for i in ventas['productos']:
                    detalle_venta = Detalle_Venta()
                    detalle_venta.id_detalle_venta = venta.id_venta
                    detalle_venta.id_producto = int(i['id_producto'])
                    detalle_venta.cantidad = int(i['cantidad'])
                    detalle_venta.subtotal = float(i['subtotal'])
                    detalle_venta.save()
            else:
                data['error'] = 'No ha ingresado a ninguna opción'
        except Exception as e:
            data['error'] = str(e)
        return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

Comment: Can you include the full stack-trace for the JS error? The error message doesn't align with the code you've shared.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in 'id_cliente'
    at p (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at mensaje_error (functions.js:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (form.js:156)
    at c (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at l (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: Please include the relevant portion of `form.js` and `functions.js`. The stacktrace mentions both.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/kkRGdXnW